# warrning: React.jsx: type is invalid -, caught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, react-dom, react-dom-server

my code seems fine but nothing come out,
my App.js

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

and
index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
    import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import Header from './components/Header';
    import Footer from './components/Footer';
    
    const routing = (
      <Router>
          <Header />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />  
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
      </Router>
    );
    
    const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(routing);
```

Header.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
    import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
    import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
    // create custom style
    import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
    
    const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
        appBar:{    //this will overwrite the Appbar css
            borderBottom:`1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        },
    }));
    function Header(){
        const classes=useStyles();
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar position="static"
                    color="white"
                    elevation={0}
                    className={classes.appBar}
                    >
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                                BlogmeUp
                            </Typography>
                        </Toolbar>    
                </AppBar>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
    export default Header;
```

okay, my code seems fine, but in my console page, they came out these error, can anyone help me?

```
    Error 1:
    warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
    Check your code at index.js:15.
```

```
    Error 2:
    Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
        at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:28439:1)
        at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:28465:1)
        at createChild (react-dom.development.js:15109:1)
        at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:15404:1)
        at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15821:1)
        at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
        at updateContextProvider (react-dom.development.js:21154:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21649:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
```

```
    Error 3:
    react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Location.Provider> component:
    
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52630:15)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50819:5)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

```
    Error 4:
    Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
        at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:28439:1)
        at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:28465:1)
        at createChild (react-dom.development.js:15109:1)
        at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:15404:1)
        at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15821:1)
        at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
        at updateContextProvider (react-dom.development.js:21154:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21649:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

and my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "blogapi",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
        "@mui/material": "^5.11.12",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Actually I following a tutorial from youtube, https://youtu.be/soxd_xdHR0o?t=6531, I followed what the tutor did, but at the end he got positive output, but I encounter numbers of error, can anyone help me?

Comment: pretty sure you have to pass a component to `root.render`, not simply jsx

Comment: @nullptr I do not understand, how to root.render? can you provide me some explanation?

Comment: the `root.render` is in your index.js. the `routing` variable you pass into the function should be a component, while you are simply passing a jsx element